# does this cable (hdmi cable for galaxy s4) works for Grand Prime or grand prime plus

Tags: samsung-galaxy-grand

does this cable

[image]

works for Grand Prime or grand prime plus

P.S.   i have RROS 7.1.2 Rom Installed On My grand Prime And The OTG Function Works Properly

Answer (score 2):

No. These cables rely on the phone supporting MHL (more than just OTG), which the Grand series, being low-end phones, [clearly don't](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_grand_prime-review-1178p3.php).